# Matlab :Error in Matrix dimensions

Tags: matlab, modeling, curve-fitting, estimation

I am interested in modelling the modified Shape analysis for which i have written a function which interpolates the Experimental values and also the curve which fits approximately the interpolated data

When i compute interpolation i am obtaining Matrix mismatch error, please kindly review it and let me know my My mistake

```
function [c_i,c_f,c_e] = M_shape_analysis(t,S,a1,a2,td,tmax,alpha,Be,p,q,r,k_el,k1,k2,k3)
%Modified Shape_analysis and estimating K3 
%  Interpolation of measured Data points



c_i = zeros(size(t));

ind = (t > td) & (t < tmax);
c_i(ind) = S *(1 - exp(-alpha*t(ind)));
%c_t(ind)= (A_max*K_1*(t(ind)/(k2+k3)-(td*(k2+k3)/(k2+k3).^2)-(td/(k2+k3) -(td*(k2+k3)/(k2+k3).^2))*exp(-(k2+k3)*(t(ind)-td)))+(0.5*K_2*(t(ind)-td).^2));


ind = (t >= tmax);

a3 =(S *(1 - exp(-alpha*t(ind))) -(a1+a2));
c_i(ind) = a1*exp(-p * (t(ind) - tmax))+ a2*exp(-q * (t(ind) - tmax)) + a3*exp(-r * (t(ind) - tmax));
%c_t(ind) =((K_1*(A/(k2+k3-B))*(exp(B*(t(ind)-tmax))- exp(-(k2+k3)*(t(ind)-tmax)))+(K_2*(A/B)*(1+exp(B*(t(ind)-tmax))))));


%ft = fittype('Input_function(t, a1, a2, a3, b1, b2, b3, td, tmax)', 'independent', 't');

%fo = fit(t, c, ft,'StartPoint', [20000, 20000, 20000, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 10, 30],'Lower', [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]);


%plot(t,c_t);
hold all;
subplot(2, 2, 2);
plot(t, c_i,'x');
axis([0 50 -2000 80000]);
xlabel time ;
ylabel concentration ;



%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   % Fitting the measured Data

ind = (t > td) & (t < tmax);

c_f(ind)= conv(((t(ind) - td) ./ (tmax - td) * (a1 + a2 + a3)),(k1*exp(-(k2+k3)*t(ind)+((k1*k3)/(k2+k3-k_el)))),'same');


ind = (t >= tmax);

c_f(ind) = conv((a1 * exp(-b1 * (t(ind) - tmax))+ a2 * exp(-b2 * (t(ind) - tmax))) + a3 * exp(-b3 * (t(ind) - tmax)),(k1*exp(-(k2+k3)*t(ind)+((k1*k3)/(k2+k3-k_el)))),'same');


hold all;
subplot(2, 2,4);
plot(t, c_f);
axis([0 50 -2000 80000]);
xlabel time ;
ylabel concentration ;

%plot(ts, Input_function(ts, fo.a1, fo.a2, fo.a3, fo.b1, fo.b2, fo.b3, fo.td, fo.tmax));

%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   % Plotting K3 Estimate : Fitted curve

  DV_free= k1/(k2+k3);

  ind = (t >= tmax);
   c_e(ind) = DV_free* exp(-Be*t(ind));

subplot(2, 2, 6);
plot(t, c_e); 

axis([0 50 -2000 80000]);
xlabel time ;
ylabel concentration ;



end
```

Following is the error that i am obtaining

```
Error using  * 
Inner matrix dimensions must agree.

Error in M_shape_analysis (line 17)
c_i(ind) = a1*exp(-p * (t(ind) - tmax))+ a2*exp(-q * (t(ind) - tmax)) + a3*exp(-r *
(t(ind) - tmax));
```

Kindly let me know where i have mistaken in my modelling

Comment: The definition of a3 in the previous line will result in an array when length(ind)>1 . So `a3 * exp(...)` will give you an error. Use `.*` instead

Answer (score 0):

I cannot point out where the exact error is because I am unaware of dimensions of your input arguments. The error is due to the fact that you are using `*` operator when either:

1. You want to perform matrix multiplication when the dimensions of the two matrices being multiplied are not in agreement. For example, one has to be a `mxn` and the other has to be a `nxk` matrix. I am assuming you are aware of this.
2. You want to perform element-wise multiplication and not matrix multiplication. If that is the case, then you have to use `.*` operator.  If you want to multiply scalar with a vector (or matrix), you can use either operator.

I believe point no. 2 is the cause of the error.

Read [`times`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/times.html) vs. [`mtimes`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mtimes.html) i.e. (`.*` vs `*`).